# Should we allow photos to be posted for help with determining the date?

Tags: discussion

Would it be appropriate to post a photo and ask that people help identify visual cues that would help date the photo?

Comment: Phew! I wondered what you meant by "dating" there. I had visions of this turning into an all together different type of site  :-)

Comment: I changed the title to avoid more inappropriate visions. :-)

Comment: I really like photo dating questions; others seem to also.

Comment: I would have left the title as it was. This SE site is a bit humourless at the moment. I don't care whether the rules & reg allow for humour - this was priceless though

Comment: @ACProctor - Humor is okay as an aside. We all love a good laugh; it just can't be the only reason for your post. ;)

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/

Answer (score 5):

My opinion is yes. We already have three questions in the [photo-dating](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photo-dating) tag, all of which have a good amount of votes (one with 21) and no downvotes. I don't see any problem with them.

The only plausible argument is that they could be too localized. However, If I had a photo in question, I could look through the existing questions to see how it was done. If I still had problems, I would ask a new question, but my point is that these questions would help more people than just the asker.

As a side note, I find these questions quite interesting (not that I'm any good at identifying them, though). It would be a shame if they were declared off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I think absolutely we should. The techniques are of general interest, even if the specific photo may not be.

Comment: Given the strong support for "yes", should we consider "What supporting information should you post with the photo?" Place etc?

Comment: Ideas:
Location, if known
* Photographer's Marks, if present.  Anything known about the photographer.
* Anything that is on the back of the photo -- include image of both sides if appropriate
* Anything that is not obvious from the picture: dimensions, embossing, type of paper, color of ink
* Anything already known that can help narrow the date range

Comment: @Fortiter et al, maybe the topic of supporting info deserves its own answer?

Comment: @womanamongmen, maybe the topic of supporting info deserves its own answer?