# What supporting information should you post with a photo for help with determining the date?

Tags: discussion

Due to positive response to the question [should-we-allow-photos-to-be-posted-for-help-with-determining-the-date](https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/should-we-allow-photos-to-be-posted-for-help-with-determining-the-date), @ColeValleyGirl suggested that we have a separate discussion on what supporting information should be recommended.

Let's discuss.

From that earlier thread:

- Location / Place
- Photographer's Marks, if present. Anything known about the photographer.
- Anything that is on the back of the photo -- include image of both sides if appropriate
- Anything that is not obvious from the picture: dimensions, embossing, type of paper, color of ink

What else?

Comment: I'd add watermarks, but that could fall into photographer's marks.

Comment: Type of photograph -- cabinet card, carte de visite, tin type, Polaroid, 35mm, etc.